Environment variables in Vitepress are not working
I am using Vitepress in my project:
{
  "scripts": {
    "docs:dev": "vitepress dev",
    "docs:build": "vitepress build",
    "docs:preview": "vitepress preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "vitepress": "1.3.0"
  }
}

The folder structure is:
myproj/
|- .vitepress
    |- config.mjs
    |- ...
|- package.json
|- .env
|- .env.production
|- ...

I define two envvars in the two envfiles:

VITE_APP_TITLE
VITE_APP_ENV

I reference them inside config.mjs:
export default {
    lang: 'en-US',
    title: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_TITLE,
    description: 'My doc.',
    head: [['link', { rel: 'icon', href: '/dp-docs/favicon.ico' }]],
}

When I run npm run docs:dev, I get this:
failed to load config from /Users/me/Documents/myproj/.vitepress/config.mjs
failed to start server. error:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'VITE_APP_TITLE')

How am I supposed to correctly use env vars in Vitepress?

Try using process.env instead of import.meta.env

process.env does not contain the env vars I placed in the files :(
